# separate admin and root rewrite rules (mod_rewrite)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

this is my current htaccess and i use mod_rewrite

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^/?admin/.+$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin/index.php [L]
```

I need to rewrite admin requests to the `admin/index.php` 
and other requests to `/index.php`.
example:
`localhost/example` to `/index.php`
`localhost/foo/bar` to `/index.php`
`localhost/admin/login/` to `admin/index.php`
`localhost/admin/pages/` to `admin/index.php`

above rules working fine but it apply to css styles or javascripts too. that means `admin/js/jquery.js` will rewrite to `admin/index.php` too(the file path exist). what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to duplicate the 2 conditions, which only apply to the very next `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^/?admin/.+$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin/index.php [L]
```

Comment: worked for `admin/foo` but still same problem on `admin/foo/bar/...`